# CasperJS - DOM methods don't get executed inside evaluate() function

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

This is the the part of the code which is problametic:

```
var obj = {};


function putInObject() {
     obj.title = document.querySelector('[itemprop="title"]').innerText;
     obj.description = document.querySelector('[itemprop="description"]').innerText;
}


casper.then(function(){
    casper.wait(1000,function(){

        links = this.evaluate(getItemLinks);

        casper.each(links, function(self, link) {
            self.thenOpen(link, function() {

                this.echo(this.getTitle());

                this.wait(7000, function(){
                    console.log("**************** \n WebPage is loaded \n ****************");

                    // Appearantly, The putInObject() doesn't run and "obj" remains null

                    casper.evaluate(putInObject);
                    this.echo(obj);

                });

            });
        });
    });
});
```

the `putInObject()` function doesn't run, even I replaced `casper.evaluate(putInObject);` with this:

```
this.evaluate(function() {
     obj.title = document.querySelector('[itemprop="title"]').innerText;
     obj.description = document.querySelector('[itemprop="description"]').innerText;
});
```

But it didn't work either and obj is printed to console like `[object Object]`.

The `this.echo(this.getTitle());` however, works fine and prints the title of the page in the console.

This the log of the above code:

```
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://example.com/category/section/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://example.com/category/section/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://example.com/category/section/"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/0F7S7QWJ0Ac.js?version=42#channel=f1413c20e7ccaa&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 12/28 https://example.com/category/section/ (HTTP 200)
WebPage's Title: Section Name
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 12/28: done in 81055ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 13/29 https://example.com/category/section/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 13/29: done in 81075ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 7000ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 14/30 https://example.com/category/section/ (HTTP 200)
****************
WebPage is loaded
****************
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 1):

`page.evaluate` is like a portal into another world that is not the same as ours. There *may be* an object by the name of `obj` there, but it's not the same as `obj` declared at the start of your CasperJs script. These are differrent objects. What happens in `page.evaluate`, stays in `page.evaluate` - unless you *specifically* request some data be returned back.

```
// This function will run inside of a web-page, not in the CasperJS script
function putInObject() {
     var obj = {}; // UPDATED: here we also need to init this object
     obj.title = document.querySelector('[itemprop="title"]').innerText;
     obj.description = document.querySelector('[itemprop="description"]').innerText;

     // return data from a web page context to CasperJS context
     return obj;
}

...

     // receive data in CasperJS context
     obj = casper.evaluate(putInObject);

     // If you want to view object's contents
     console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Thank you Vaviloff. I did get what you say and used your tips butl got `null` from `this.echo(obj);`. Here's the amended Code: https://pastebin.com/96D3dSVs . About the`console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));`, I assume should use it in the webpage context, So I put it inside the `putInObject()` function before `return` statement, But nothing was printed in my terminal (casperJS log)

Comment: My bad, forgot to initialize `obj` object in the web page. See updated code and here's a working example (albeit in PhantomJS raw dialect): https://pastebin.com/Yvhxe2cp